# Which free VPN providers support Ubuntu?

Tags: security, vpn, privacy

Can't find any free VPN provider for Ubuntu. I tried looking into old questions but they seem to be outdated.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the Bestfreevpn. This is their [link](http://www.bestfreevpn.com/) also read [this](http://myinterestingubuntu.blogspot.com/2011/06/free-vpn-service-providers.html) for more info

Answer (score 6):

Another vpn provider's services that work on Ubuntu are those by a company called  [Securitykiss](http://www.securitykiss.com/). **However**, the free user is **only** allowed **300** mb per day, but this may be enough if you are using it in a cyber cafe, for example, to secure your connection.

The setup of `Securitykiss` requires much more effort than `bestfreevpn`, so it is up to you which service you choose. You can either use `PPTP` (instructions [here](http://www.securitykiss.com/resources/tutorials/pptp_ubuntu/)) or `openvpn` (instructions [here](http://www.securitykiss.com/resources/tutorials/conf_linux_nm/)).

Before you can follow either of these sets of instructions, however, you need to get a configuration generated for Linux based systems [from here](http://www.securitykiss.com/resources/download/linux/) and then log on to the [client area here](https://www.securitykiss.com/panel/) and download your package which contains further configuration details.

`Securitykiss` takes a bit to setup and is **limited** to 300mb for the free user, but is an example of a 'free' vpn service, of which there are very few 'free' examples out there.

I have just been experimenting with it and wanted to bring it to the attention of the community, as it does work successfully on Ubuntu and the instructions on the site are tailored to Ubuntu so I thought it might be of interest.

Comment: I suffered a phishing attempt when I used SecurityKiss and logged in to an online service. The service got a log in request from China, refused it and notified me. I switched passwords and will not use SecurityKiss again.

Answer (score 3):

**If you mean VPN Clients check this:**

PPTP (Microsoft VPN)

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-pptp
```

Cisco VPN

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-vpnc
```

OpenVPN

```
sudo apt-get install network-manager-openvpn
```

**If you mean VPN Servers check this:**

OpenVPN

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OpenVPN

PoPToP

http://cviorel.easyblog.ro/2009/02/09/how-to-set-up-a-vpn-server-on-ubuntu/

Comment: What is the use of setting up a VPN server? Can it give better security?

Comment: VPN Server is used to give VPN clients access to your local private network and allow them to initiate connections to your network

Comment: did my answer just work for you?

Comment: PPTP is installed by default and is enough to get BestFreeVpn working. So your answer didn't work :)

Answer (score 0):

**Please do not use a free VPN provider**. He will sell your data, what else is his source of income?

Have a look at [PrivacyTools](https://www.privacytools.io/providers/vpn/) for a list with recommendations (paid).

> Warning
>
> Using a VPN will not keep your browsing habits anonymous, nor will it
> add additional security to non-secure (HTTP) traffic.
>
> If you are looking for anonymity, you should use the Tor Browser
> instead of a VPN.
>
> If you're looking for added security, you should always ensure you're
> connecting to websites using encrypted DNS and HTTPS. A VPN is not a
> replacement for good security practices.

and

> Our recommended providers are outside the US, use encryption, accept
> Bitcoin, support OpenVPN, and have a no logging policy. Read our [full
> list of criteria](https://www.privacytools.io/providers/vpn/#criteria) for more information.

the most popular choice is ProtonVPN.

Answer (score 0):

Try Open Vpn, A Very Good Vpn Provider .. https://openvpn.net/